# How can I write this query to filter the results properly?

Tags: mysql, database, left-join

I have 3 tables I am wanting to join:

#### equipment

- equipmentNo
- assetNo
- subCategoryNo
- doNo
- userNo
- locationNo
- isocNo
- emergency
- ariNo
- makeNo
- modelNo
- serial
- kitNo
- purchaseDate
- purchasePrice
- comments
- surplused

  #### employees
- userNo
- fname
- lname
- doNo
- emergency

  #### subcategories
- subCategoryNo
- subCategory
- categoryNo
- replacementCycle

I need to get a set of data that includes all of the equipment information ordered by 'doNo' and 'lname' from employees which are linked by 'userNo' and the equipment 'subCategoryNo' needs to be only those from subcategories where 'categoryNo' equals 2.

I got this far before getting lost and confused.

```
SELECT equipment.*, employees.lname, employees.fname 
FROM equipment 
LEFT JOIN employees 
  USING (userNo) 
ORDER BY equipment.doNo, employees.lname;
```

I could not figure out how to limit this to only 'categoryNo' 2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT equipment.*, employees.lname, employees.fname 
FROM equipment 
LEFT JOIN employees USING (userNo) 
JOIN subcategories USING(subCategoryNo)
WHERE subcategories.categoryNo=2
ORDER BY equipment.doNo, employees.lname;
```

Comment: Thanks :) Works great. I get lost doing more than one join at a time.